# Android Studio Packages are not nesting properly

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

This happened all of a sudden, so I have no idea what is going on.

[image]

All the packages are being shown separately.

I have not changed any project settings, and I tried the following:

- Invalidated cache.
- Updated android studio (beta 2 to beta 7, completely separate).

If I try to create a new subpackage somewhere, it will create a new unnested listing as shown.

This is affecting all of my projects opened from the same AS version.
My Stable 2.3.0 version opens things just fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Click the gear in the top right corner of the project view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "gear" icon in the top right corner of the project view has some option that'll toggle the option to display flattened  packages

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to solve this is by  toggling the "flatten packages" check mark. To get there, select the "gear/settings" button at the top right corner of the project view, locate "flatten packages" and uncheck it.